# Преобразование столбцов в строку SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, оптимизация-запросов

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть две таблицы. В одной таблице содержаться значения, а в другой свойства этого значения и наименования свойств. У одного значения может быть несколько свойств, но с конкретным наименованием только одно свойство. Как мне вывести результат в единую таблицу, преобразовав строки в столбцы?

```
TABLE 1
ID  DATA_TABLE1
1    data0
2    data1

TABLE 2
ID ID_FROM_TABLE_1  VALUE   PROPERTY
1       0             1       unique0
2       0             2       unique1        
3       0             1       unique2
4       1             1       unique0
5       1             2       unique1
6       1             3       unique4
```

Если осуществить подобный запрос:

```
SELECT table1.ID, DATA_TABLE1, VALUE, PROPERTY
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.ID = table2.ID_FROM_TABLE_1
```

Результат будет таким:

```
ID   DATA_TABLE1    VALUE    PROPERTY
 1      data0          1     unique0
 1      data0          2     unique1
 1      data0          1     unique2
 2      data1          1     unique0
 2      data1          2     unique1
 2      data1          3     unique4
```

А хотелось бы:

```
ID   DATA     PROP0       PROP1       PROP2      PROP4
 1   data0      1          2            1         NULL
 2   data1      1          2            NULL       3
```

Comment: А что если вместо создания колонок PROP* вернуть эти сгруппированные данные в виде json/xml?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- столбцы
SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(REPLACE(t.PROPERTY, 'unique', 'PROP')) + ','
    --@columns+=t.PROPERTY + ','
FROM 
    table2 t
GROUP BY t.PROPERTY
ORDER BY t.PROPERTY;

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

--print @columns;

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        ID_FROM_TABLE_1 + 1 as ID,
        ID_FROM_TABLE_1,
        [VALUE],
        REPLACE(PROPERTY, ''unique'', ''PROP'') as PROPERTY
    FROM 
        table2
) t 
PIVOT(
    MIN(t.[VALUE]) 
    FOR t.PROPERTY IN ('+ @columns +')
) AS pivot_table;';

-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

а дальше уже сами имя таблицы для столбца DATA привяжите.
решение для MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

Мне в голову пришло только такое решение:

```
SELECT
  table1.ID,
  table1.[DATA_TABLE1] AS [table1 DATA],
  (SELECT TOP(1) table2.value
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.ID_FROM_TABLE_1=table1.id AND table2.property='unique0') AS 'PROP0',
  (SELECT TOP(1) table2.value
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.ID_FROM_TABLE_1=table1.id AND table2.property='unique1') AS 'PROP1',
  (SELECT TOP(1) table2.value
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.ID_FROM_TABLE_1=table1.id AND table2.property='unique2') AS 'PROP2',
  (SELECT TOP(1) table2.value
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.ID_FROM_TABLE_1=table1.id AND table2.property='unique4') AS 'PROP4'
FROM
  table1
```

Но если я правильно понимаю, то получается, что на выбор каждой строки, совершается ещё 4 выбора

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю через CASE. Результирующая таблица будет немного отличаться , напоминать сводную Excel.

```
    SELECT ID, DATATABLE_ID AS DATA,
    (CASE WHEN VALUE=1 AND 
    PROPERTY=UNIQUE0 
    THEN 1 END) AS PROP0,
    (CASE WHEN VALUE=2 AND 
    PROPERTY=UNIQUE1
    THEN 2 END) AS PROP1,
    (CASE WHEN VALUE=1 AND 
    PROPERTY=UNIQUE2 
    THEN 1 END) AS PROP2,
    (CASE WHEN VALUE=3 AND 
    PROPERTY=UNIQUE4 
    THEN 3 END) AS PROP3
    FROM \* созданная Вами таблица с LEFT JOIN *\
```